# Implementing magic

Tags: java, oop

When we implement an interface in a class we need to make sure that all methods defined by that interface appear in source code of class. So why does this code compile easily?

```
interface A {
    void f();
}
class X {
    public void f() {}
}
class Y extends X implements A {
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it?  `Y` is inheriting the method `f` from `X` and raising it to `public`, which is allowed...

Comment: If some interface methods is not implemented in derived class but it's there in base class so it will find definication from base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `X` already implements the `f()` method, `Y` extends `X`, which makes it inherit the implementation of said method.

For this case, the resolution goes by method signature. And the class `X`, even though not implementing the A interface, has a method with the right signature. So the implementing class, `Y` has that method too.

I'd say that having such a construction - while valid - should be used only when there is no way to make the class `X` also implement the interface (external library, code freeze, bad boss, etc), because it makes some head scratching about what is happening... One reading the code, must navigate to the class `X`, and find the `f()` method there...

<sub>First I misread the question, and these would be valid  when `X implements A` is present too.

<del>Even though you explixitly specified the `X implements A` clause, that does not matter - in this case that is redundant.</del></sub>

If `X` was abstract, and `Y` didn't implement `f()`, `Y` would be forced to implement the method, unless `Y` is declared abstract too.

Comment: Are you talking about "X implements A" record?

Comment: Here X implemented method presented in your interface

Comment: Just a minor comment - it is not redundant to define the `implements` because otherwise you wouldn't be able to use a `Y` instance as an `A` instance even though it implements the necessary methods.

Comment: No @ppeterka66, `X` does NOT implement `A`.  You can't point a variable of type `A` to an object of class `X`.

Comment: @DavidWallace you are right, of course, as a standard action, I blame my phone, the world, and extraterrestial lifeforms for not correcting my obvious error....

Answer (score 2):

If some interface method is not implemented in the derived class but it's there in the base class, the implementation from the base class will be used.

## interface

```
interface A {
    void f();
}
```

## base class

```
class X {
    public void f() {}
}
```

Here the compiler checks for method `f()`, and if its definition is not written in the same class, then it will look in the base class for the definition. **This is a basic property of inheritance**

## derived class

```
class Y extends X implements A {
   

}
```

You can understand it as `f()` being indirectly present in class `Y`.

**First compiler will read class `Y`,   then it will go to interface `A`  and then it will search for method `f()` in class `Y`.  If it's not written over there then it will search in the base class, which is `x`**

Comment: Thanks David Wallace for improving english i will take care these thing in future.

Answer (score 0):

From where you got that statement that **it must be in the source code of the class**?

A class must implement all methods defined by a implemented `interface` or parent (`abstract`) `class` or else must be declared `abstract`.

So of course class Y will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Simple concept in java is **child inherit the properties of its parent**, if this is the case then `Y` already have `f()` available. This is no magic.

Answer (score 0):

Although class **X** does not implement interface **A**, it does have a public method that happens to match the interface method signature.
When class **Y** extends class **X** it inherits that method and the compiler will treat it as a valid implementation to the interface method.